# Rails has_many :through with custom column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many

I have 2 model associated with module ProjectsUsersRole:

Users can join more than 1 Projects, Project have lots of users, and user join the project with a role saying "admin" or "member":

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects_users_role
  has_many :projects, :through => :projects_users_role
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects_users_role
  has_many :users, :through => :projects_users_role
end

class ProjectsUsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :project

  attr_accessible :role, :user, :project
end
```

I can get the project of current user:

@projects = current_user.projects

But how to get all the users in the projects with role?

Comment: You question is a little confusing. Could you elaborate on exactly what you want to return, with what data you have?

Comment: Sorry but that still isn't enough information. 'How to get all the users in the projects with role?' what does that mean? What role? What project?

Comment: So to clarify, you want to get all of the users with a certain role within all of the projects which current_user is a member of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@projects.each do |project|
   project.projects_users_role.each do |r|
        debug r.role
   end
end
```